# comparing data type of sql server and ms access in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access, ado.net

Is there any method to compare the data types of two different Databases.

Comment: Suggestion : Use single data provider (OleDB) to read and write rows of different databases.

Comment: I can not use only OleDb provider to read and write different database because it had compatibility issue with 64 bit os.

Comment: What provider you want to use to access Ms-Acces? Is it ODBC?

Comment: For access it is ODBC, for Oracle and SqlServer it is ADO.NET.

Comment: Also consolidating on OLE DB is a bad idea, since Microsoft is killing off OLE DB in SQL Server.

Comment: But if you do want to, I'm not aware of any compatibility issues with x64. SQL Server, ACE and ODAC all come in an x64 flavour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

| Jet Engine (Access) | Sql-Server | C# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text (len < 256) | char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar | string |
| Memo | text, ntext, char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar | string |
| Byte | tinyint | byte |
| Integer | smallint | short |
| Long Integer | integer (int) | int |
| Single | real | float |
| Double | float | double |
| Replication ID | uniqueidentifier | Guid |
| Decimal | decimal | decimal |
| Date/Time | smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2 | DateTime |
| Binary (8 bytes) | timestamp, rowversion (Since V2008) | byte[] (8 bytes) |
| Currency | smallmoney, money | decimal |
| AutoNumber | int + identity property | int |
| Yes/No | bit | bool |
| OLE Object | image | byte[] |
| Hyperlink |  | string |
|  | binary, varbinary | byte[] |

I took this information from [How to Migrate from Access to SQL Server 2000](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917602.aspx) and added the C# column.

Note also that most types are nullable in the databases. Map nullable columns to `Nullable<T>` (`T?`) in C# unless the .NET type is a reference type.

Comment: Thanks Olivier, I will use it then let you know its working for me or not.